# Knockout js: Viewmodel property not being bound

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aaScC/

Please check in the example, the Score property has 3.5 value but it is being displayed as 1. I know the score property is bound to dropdown value so its coming as 1. But i want 3.5 to be displayed. Please help.

```
var GoalsModel = function (goals) {
    var self = this;

    self.goals = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(goals, function (goal) { return new Goal(goal) }));


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you just make the `select` element invisible. You don't want the element at all. You can use bindings [if](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) or [ifnot](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/ifnot-binding.html) to control this.

Here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/waxwing/aaScC/1/ . I wrapped the `select` inside a `span` to make it work, but you can also use [virtual bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) if you don't like to change your DOM structure.

Comment: Thanks it worked like a gem. I didnt know this. Actually i thought of changing my backend model, but you saved my day. Thanks a lot. I dont have the reputation to vote up your answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aaScC/8/.. The subgoals which are having dropdown, self score is not being displayed. Please help.